# Fourier Transform of Bessel function with square root argument

Tags: special-functions, integral-transforms

Fourier Transform of the following function: 
$\xi(\alpha,\tilde{\alpha},\beta)=\frac{J_{1}\left(\varrho_{0}k_{0}n\sqrt{\sin^{2}\alpha+\sin^{2}\tilde{\alpha}-2\sin\alpha\,\sin\tilde{\alpha}\cos\beta}\right)}{\sqrt{\sin^{2}\alpha+\sin^{2}\tilde{\alpha}-2\sin\alpha\,\sin\tilde{\alpha}\cos\beta}}$
,
i.e to find 
$\hat{\xi}(\alpha,\tilde{\alpha},m)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\xi(\alpha,\tilde{\alpha},\beta)\exp(-im\beta)d\beta$

I tried using addition theorem of Bessel functions and I get quite cumbersome expressions. 
Any help in getting it from standard integrals?

Comment: Have you tried with integral representations of the Bessel functions?

Comment: I tried but couldnt make progress after a certain point.